# python pandas getting the last value of the column different than other value

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a pandas DF as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['Bar', 'Bar', 'Restaurant', 'Restaurant','disco','disco','school','school'],
                 'type': ['fig', 'ref', 'ref', 'fig','ref','ref','fig','ref'],
                  'int':[1,2,3,2,5,6,3,8]},
                  index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
df
```

I would like to add another column called figure that will tell me the figure number of the ref column, this value being the upper most close value with type 'fig'

the image explains it:

[image]

I know how to do it looping one by one over the elements and adding one by one the elements, or conversely using several "help columns" like:

```
    import numpy as np 
df['help'] = np.where( (df['type'] == 'fig') , df['int'], 0)

help_list= df['help'].tolist()
help_list

column_list=[]
trailing_fig = 0
for element in help_list:
    if element == 0:
        column_list.append(trailing_fig)
    else:
        column_list.append(0)
        trailing_fig = element
        
column_list
```

Now I am sure there is a pythonic-pandanic way to formulate that.
This is not just about making the code beautiful, but more efficient

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make do with `ffill`:

```
df['figure'] = df['int'].where(df['type'].eq('fig')).ffill()
```

Output:

```
     location type  int  figure
1         Bar  fig    1     1.0
2         Bar  ref    2     1.0
3  Restaurant  ref    3     1.0
4  Restaurant  fig    2     2.0
5       disco  ref    5     2.0
6       disco  ref    6     2.0
7      school  fig    3     3.0
8      school  ref    8     3.0
```

Comment: I did not dare to ask for a one-liner but somehow I thought there would be one. Thanks a lot. thats great

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

get values where `type` column is not equal to `fig`, create a second column to generate values based on the number of `fig` in the `type` column. The rest builds on downward fill (`ffill`) and `numpy where` to get your final output

```
df["temp1"] = df["type"].ne("fig").astype(int)
df.loc[df["type"].eq("fig"), "temp2"] = range(1, df["type"].eq("fig").sum() + 1)
df["temp2"] = df["temp2"].ffill()
df["temp1"] = np.where(df.temp1 == 1, df.temp2, df.temp1)
df.iloc[:, :-1]

location       type int temp1
1   Bar         fig 1   0.0
2   Bar         ref 2   1.0
3   Restaurant  ref 3   1.0
4   Restaurant  fig 2   0.0
5   disco       ref 5   2.0
6   disco       ref 6   2.0
7   school      fig 3   0.0
8   school      ref 8   3.0
```